# Как добавить существующую запись из базы в форму?

Tags: django

Путь будет такая ситуация. Рабочие бригады заходят в свою учетку и заполняют форму о проделанной работе. В конце месяца бригадир входит в свою учетку и видит все эти записи, он должен их подтвердить (чекбокс), возможно исправить, и написать комменты. 
Пусть модель выглядит так:

```
class TaskList(models.Model):
    worker = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date = models.DateField()
    signed = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Формы:

```
class TaskFormWorker(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskList
        fields = ['task', 'date']

class TaskFormManager(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskList
        fields = [f.name for f in TaskList._meta.get_fields()]
```

То есть Бригадир жмет на задачу в списке задач и попадает в детализацию, доступную для редактирования.

Как сделать так, чтобы данные по выбранной задаче из базы попадали в форму?

Например, я через URL передам ID задачи, получу экземпляр `TaskList`, но как его передать форме?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете создать форму из модели. Для этого воспользуйтесь стандартным классом Django [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Пример из документации

```
>>> from django.forms import ModelForm
>>> from myapp.models import Article

# Create the form class.
>>> class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
...     class Meta:
...         model = Article
...         fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content', 'reporter']

# Creating a form to add an article.
>>> form = ArticleForm()

# Creating a form to change an existing article.
>>> article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
```

При рендере ModelForm с переданным экземпляром модели вы получите форму с заполненными данными.

Документация:

- [На английском](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/)
- [На русском](http://djbook.ru/rel1.6/topics/forms/modelforms.html)